# Extract multiple string groups in same column pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
test = {'title': ['Undeclared milk in Burnbrae', 'Undeclared milk in certain Bumble', 'Certain cheese products may contain listeria', 'Ocean brand recalled due to Salmonella', 'IQF Raspberries due to Listeria']}
example = pd.DataFrame(test)
example
```

```
    title
0   Undeclared milk in Burnbrae
1   Undeclared milk in certain Bumble
2   Certain cheese products may contain listeria
3   Ocean brand recalled due to Salmonella
4   IQF Raspberries due to Listeria
```

And I want to extract the following strings in the same column. I want my result to look like this:

```
test = {'hazard': ['Undeclared milk', 'Undeclared milk', 'listeria', 'Salmonella', 'Listeria'], 'title': ['Undeclared milk in Burnbrae', 'Undeclared milk in certain Bumble', 'Certain cheese products may contain listeria', 'Ocean brand recalled due to Salmonella', 'IQF Raspberries due to Listeria']}
example2 = pd.DataFrame(test)
example2
```

```
     hazard          title
0   Undeclared milk Undeclared milk in Burnbrae
1   Undeclared milk Undeclared milk in certain Bumble
2   listeria        Certain cheese products may contain listeria
3   Salmonella      Ocean brand recalled due to Salmonella
4   Listeria        IQF Raspberries due to Listeria
```

Essentially my separators are `in`, `may contain` and `due to`

```
example['hazard'] = example['title'].str.extract(r'^(.*?) in\b')
example['hazard'] = example['title'].str.extract(r'\b may contain (.*)$')
example['hazard'] = example['title'].str.extract(r'\b due to (.*)$')
```

I wrote the code above to test each separator but would like to extract all in the same column.

How can I do this?

I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more first principles approach that gets the same outcome:

```
def func(s: str):
    check1 = re.search(r'^(.*?) in\b',s)
    check2 = re.search(r'\b may contain (.*)$',s)
    check3 = re.search(r'\b due to (.*)$',s)
    if check1:
        return check1.group(1)
    elif check2:
        return check2.group(1)
    elif check3:
        return check3.group(1)
    else:
        return np.nan

example["hazard"] = example["title"].apply(func)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join your seperators into list, and join them via `"|".join` to transform this into a larger pattern. From there, `Series.str.extract` can get all of the matches, and we reshape to match the original size.

```
seperators = [r"^(.*?) in\b", r"\b may contain (.*)$", r"\b due to (.*)$"]
sep_pattern = r"|".join(seperators)

example["hazard"] = (example["title"].str.extract(sep_pattern)
                       .stack()
                       .droplevel(1))

print(example)
                                          title           hazard
0                   Undeclared milk in Burnbrae  Undeclared milk
1             Undeclared milk in certain Bumble  Undeclared milk
2  Certain cheese products may contain listeria         listeria
3        Ocean brand recalled due to Salmonella       Salmonella
4               IQF Raspberries due to Listeria         Listeria
```

Comment: It's returning a null value in all rows because it is not joining the "| " to the list of strings. So it;s not recognizing the "or" condition.

Comment: Just re-tested this snippet and it still works for me `pandas 1.1.5` Not sure why it's giving you nulls.

Comment: I updated my pandas version and it works now, weird. Do you know why instead of writing example['title'].str.extract(r'^(.*?) in\\b|\\b may contain (.*)$|\\b due to (.*)$') it doesn't work? Thank you for the help!